# Google Maps API v3 Geocoder.geocode() argument "location" not works

Tags: google-maps-api-3

There is "location" property in [GeocoderRequest](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest) object, that defines "LatLng about which to search. Optional.", I'm trying to use it, but it does not work:

`geocoder.geocode( { address: control.value, location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.938531, 30.313497)}, function(results, status) {....})`

For example, when I'm searching for some address in 59.938531, 30.313497, so `results` contains 2 objects, and the right address has index `[1]` but not `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The location is not valid. You want either address or latLng.  The `GeocodeRequest` object literal contains the following fields:

```
{
 address: string,
 latLng: LatLng,
 bounds: LatLngBounds,
 language: string,
 region: string
}
```

Comment: Why "location" property is not valid? Check http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest - there is description of "location" property

Comment: It looks like a error in the documentation. Why do you want to use address and location at the same time?

If you use address you will do a geocode to get the latLng, if you use latLng then you will do a reverse geocode to get the address.

Answer (score 1):

Language parameter in JavaScript call by geocoder not supported:

http://code.google.com/intl/th-TH/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder